# How to fix timing function when I refresh browser each time?

Tags: javascript

I want to count down remaining time from today's time to specific time. But when I refresh browser it starts from starting. I can not fix this problem.Here is my source code:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 20 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('test', deadline);
```

Comment: In the second to last line, `var deadline` is always set to the current date (`new Date()`) plus some amount of time. It should be made so that the deadline is a set date and not one that will change on every load.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to persist the time remaining so that the time can be used when users come back after closing the page. There are several ways to do this (cookies, etc.), but probably the easiest will be to use **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**

This would be utilized in your `getTimeRemaining` function, like this:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {

  // Check to see if there is a previous time already stored in localStorage
  if(localStorage.getItem('timeRemaining')){

     // There is, use that:
     return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('timeRemaining'));
  }

  // If not, generate the correct time remaining:

  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  // Turn answer into a string:
  var timeRemaining = JSON.stringify({
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  });

  // Store data in localStorage:
  localStorage.setItem('timeRemaining', timeRemaining);

  return timeRemaining;
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with JSON if you please write in plane JavaScript it will be helpful for me.

Comment: @RokibulHasan JSON is a standard ECMAScript object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). It is plain JavaScript.